# What does "extend immediate to 32 bits" mean in MIPS?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, machine-code, sign-extension, immediate-operand

I'm reading about the Instruction Decode (ID) phase in the MIPS datapath, and I've got the following quote: "Once operands are known, read the actual data (from registers) or extend the data to 32 bits (immediates)."

Can someone explain what the "extend the data to 32 bits (immediates)" part means? I know that registers all contain 32 bits, and I know what an immediate is. I just don't understand why you need to extend the immediate from 26 to 32 bits.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

26-bit immediates are only in jump instructions, and aren't sign- or zero-extended to 32 bit, because they're not displacements to be added/subtracted.

I-type instructions with 16-bit immediates are different.

- `addi` / `addiu` immediates are sign-extended (by duplicating the top/sign bit of the immediate to all higher bits). 
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Sign_extension
  **This allows 2's complement numbers from `-2^15` .. `+2^15-1` to be encoded.**
  **(0xFFFF8000 to 0x00007FFF)**
- `ori`/`andi`/`xori` boolean immediates are zero-extended (by setting all higher bits to zero)
  **This allows unsigned / 2's complement numbers from `0 .. 2^16-1` to be encoded.**
  **(0x00000000 to 0x0000FFFF)**

For other instructions see this [instruction-set reference](https://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~crawfis.3/cse675-02/Slides/MIPS%20Instruction%20Set.pdf) which breaks down each instruction showing 0<sup>16</sup> || [I<sub>15..0</sub>] for zero-extension or [I<sub>15</sub>]<sup>16</sup> || [I<sub>15..0</sub>] for sign-extension.

**This makes it possible to use 16-bit immediates as inputs to a 32-bit binary operation that only makes sense with 2 equal-width inputs**.  (In a simple classic MIPS pipeline, the decode stage fetches operands from registers and/or immediates.  Register inputs are always going to be 32-bit, so the ALU is wired up for 32-bit inputs.  Extending immediates to 32-bit means the rest of the CPU doesn't have to care whether the data came from an immediate or a register.)

**Also sign-extended**:

- offsets in the reg+imm16 addressing mode used by `lw`/`sw` and other load/store instructions
- relative branches (`PC += imm16<<2`)

maybe others, check the manual for instructions I didn't mention to see if they sign- or zero- extend.

---

You might be wondering "why does `addiu` sign-extend its immediate even though it's unsigned?"

Remember that there's no `subiu`, only `addiu` with a negative immediate.  Being able to add or subtract numbers in the range `-2^15 .. +2^15-1` is more useful than only being able to add `0 .. 2^16-1`.

And usually you don't want to raise an exception on signed overflow, so normally compilers use `addu` / `addiu` even on signed integers.  `addu` is badly named: it's not "for unsigned integers", it's just a wrapping-allowed / never-faulting version of `add`/`addi`.  It sort of makes sense if you think of C, where signed overflow is undefined behaviour (and thus could use `add` and raise an exception in that case if the compiler wanted to implement it that way), but unsigned integers have well-defined overflow behaviour: base 2 wraparound.

Comment: Also sign-extended: slti[u] immediates. There are also trap instructions with immediates and even more stuff is sign-extended on MIPS64 (most 32-bit ALU instructions and a few newer, MIPS64-only instructions).

Answer (score 1):

On a 32-bit CPU, most of the operations you do (like adding, subtracting, dereferencing a pointer) are done with 32-bit numbers.  When you have a number with fewer bits, you need to somehow decide what those other bits are going to be when you want to use that number in one of those operations.  The act of deciding what those new high bits are is called "extending".

Assuming you are just doing a standard zero extension or sign extension, extending is very cheap.  However, it does require some circuitry, so it makes sense that a description of the MIPS datapath would mention it.