# Set all bits of a register to 1, can ORI do that?

Tags: assembly, mips, immediate-operand

I got a few questions marked incorrect on a MIPS assembly exam, and I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out why because I don't understand why at all.

First question:

> Set all bits of register $t1 to 1

My answer was `ori $t1, $t1, -1`

---

The other two questions gave some assembly code and asked to "Write the operation performed by each assembly program." The original code was uncommented. The comments below are mine.

First short-answer question:

```
        .data
len:    .word   4
list:   .word   -4, 6, 7, -2, 1
        .text
main:   la $s0, list
        la $s1, len
        lw $t1, 0($s1)       // NOTE: 4, so loops over array
        add $t0, $zero, $zero
alpha:  lw $t2, 0($s0)
        blez $t2, beta
        add $t0, $t0, $t2
beta:   addi $t1, $t1, -1
        addi $s0, $s0, 4
        bgtz $t1, alpha
        add $v0, $zero, $t2   // NOTE: $t2 should be $t0?
        jr $ra
```

My response for the first short-answer question was: "Adds up all positive elements of array, and returns last element of array"

I thought the second last line should have $t0 instead of $t2 so that it would return the sum it calculated instead of the last element, but I asked the instructor about this during the exam and he said to treat all the given code as correct/intended even if I thought it was a mistake.

---

Second short-answer question. Again, the original code was uncommented. The comments below are mine.

```
        .data
len:    .word   4
list:   .word   -4, 6, 7, -2, 1
        .text
main:   la $s0, list
        la $s1, len
        lw $t1, 0($s1)        // $t1 = len
        add $t4, $zero, $zero // $t4 = 0
alpha:  lw $t0, 0($s0)
        add $t4, $t4, $t0     // $t4 adds up all elements of array
        addi $t1, $t1, -1
        addi $s0, $s0, 4
beta:   blez $t1, alpha
        or $v0, $t4, $zero
        jr $ra
```

My response for the second short-answer question was: "Returns the sum of all elements in the array"

If anyone could help me to figure out what did I do wrong, or if it was marked wrong?

Comment: Your answers look correct to me but note that the array length is given as `4` so the final `1` is not actually processed. Thus your instructor might have given zero points for those questions because you wrote **all** elements.

Comment: In the second short-answer question, the branch is `blez`, not `bgtz`, so it in fact never loops at all for arrays of length 2 or more. (For arrays of length 0 or 1, it runs off the end of the array.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Oops I didn't see that either :( Thanks for your response and helping clean up my question!

Answer (score 2):

First part: `ori` takes a zero-extended 16-bit immediate (like other bitwise boolean instructions).  Other MIPS instructions, including `addiu`, sign-extend their 16-bit immediate to 32 bits so `0xFFFFFFFF` *is* encodeable for those instructions<sup>1</sup>.

**`ori $t1, $t1, -1` is not encodeable as a single machine instruction**, only supported by MARS's assembler as an "extended" pseudo-instruction that materializes the constant in another register then uses it with `or`.  (For example `addiu $at, $zero, -1` / `or $t1, $t1, $at`).

You can do it in one real machine instruction (and without any input dependency):
**`addiu $t1, $zero, -1`**

---

Footnote 1: I'm not sure why this design decision was made; it's arbitrary and RISC-V chose differently (always sign extend).  But see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290060/what-does-extend-immediate-to-32-bits-mean-in-mips/55290104#55290104) for more about MIPS.

`andi` is certainly useful with all-ones in the high bits, e.g. to align a pointer with `p &= -16`.  MIPS can bitwise NOT a value using `nor` so it doesn't need `xori` with `-1` to be encodeable.  `ori` with all high bits set to `1` is likely less useful than doing something with the low 16 (instead of 15) bits of a register.

It also allows `lui / ori` for constructing 32-bit values without having to offset the high half to account for bit #15 being set (top of the low half) like you have to for `lui / addiu`.

---

The second part of your question is really a separate question; the answers to it is totally independent of how immediates work for `ori`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! So if I'm understanding correctly `ori` behaves differently depending on the value of the immediate being passed in, in the MARS assembler? Meaning if the immediate can't be zero extended then `ori` will be performed as two machine code instructions? Also why does `ori` zero extend the imm, but `addiu` sign extend it?

Comment: @apples2: Yes, MARS with the "extended pseudo-instructions" option enabled will assemble it to multiple instructions if necessary, just like it will for any instruction with a large immediate.  e.g. `addiu $t1, $t0, 0x12345678`.  That's the point of a pseudo-instruction, just like `la` or `li`.

Comment: @apples2: Why some instructions zero-extend:  That was an arbitrary decision by the architects of MIPS.  RISC-V for example always sign-extends.  Presumably MIPS designers figured that bitwise instructions are unlikely to want sign-extension, although in practice using `andi` to round down to a multiple of 8 or 16 or something (e.g. to align a pointer) does want all the high bits set, like `x &= -16`.   MIPS's choice does have the interesting property that you can construct any value from `-32768 .. 65535` in a register in one instruction, using either `addiu` or `ori`.

Comment: @apples2: updated my answer with some thoughts on why MIPS might have chosen to zero-extend.  IDK what the architects, or people with a lot of practical experience optimizing code for MIPS (especially crypto or video encoding or other bit-fiddly high performance stuff), think of that decision in hindsight.  Probably with SIMD extensions for MIPS making memory alignment more relevant, `andi` would be more relevant.

Comment: You typically set one or a small number of bits, so sign extension into the upper 16 bits is rarely needed. As you noted, `addiu` can be used to cover negative 16-bit signed constants. Signed immediates do let you drop `andi` with `-3` to a single instruction, but it also bloats bitwise ops with 32768 to **three** instructions. Alpha AXP used signed 16-bit immediates everywhere, and it created problems at bit 15, and for 64-bit values in the range `0x00000000'7FFF8000` to `0x00000000'7FFFFFFF`. The latter meant you couldn't use relocatable code in that range.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Agreed, it's a nice choice for `ori` on its own.  Having *any* instructions that work differently means a MUX somewhere, though, instead of unconditional sign-extension for I-type instructions.  Unless there's some way to piggy-back on whatever muxing is already needed to handle I-type vs. other types with a register source.  Or a 1-bit MUX for the input of the sign-extension thing to override that to zero.  So yeah it's probably not a big deal to build.  Interesting point about `+32768` which has a single bit set but would still take two insns to construct with `addiu`

Comment: Thanks for your answers, really interesting!